# Using onchange event handler to alter second select list

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, onchange

Have a form field asking for a product, these are various sizes, the second form field asks for the quantity.

The stock quantity of each product is shown in the first select, I want the second select to be a maximum of the stock available so customers cannot order more than I have available.

This is the first select (also linked to show custom pictures) Site is ASP

```
<select name="barcode" id="imageselect">
 <option value>Please Select .....</option>
 <option value="322974">6.6lbs 100m  - £21.00 ( 2 in stock )</option>
 <option value="322975">8.2lbs 100m  - £21.00 ( 3 in stock )</option>
 <option value="322976"disabled=disabled>10.4lbs 100m  - £21.00 - Out of stock</option>
 <option value="323656">13.7lbs 100ms  - £21.00 ( 4 in stock )</option>
</select>
```

This is the second select:

```
<select name="quantity">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
 <option value="6">6</option>
 <option value="7">7</option>
 <option value="8">8</option>
 <option value="9">9</option>
 <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Have tried using onchange event but with no joy.

The UK Autotrader has a very good example of this working with their car makes / models.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Validating the input? Determining the stock available for the selection?

Comment: If I am not wrong this site is just asp & not asp.net???

Comment: Just struggling with the whole onevent handler, the site is in classic ASP (not .net)

The issue I have is the value of the first select is not a stock quantity but a barcode (database field)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want...

NB: I've used a shot cut by adding a 'stock' attribute to your options, just to avoid parsing the string.

```
<option value="322974">6.6lbs 100m  - £21.00 ( 2 in stock )</option>
```

If you want to avoid this, the example below also shows you how to get the text to parse for the stock attribute.

```
$("#imageselect").change(function(event){
    var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.val();
    var $option = $("option[value="+value+"]", $this),
        text = $option.text(),   // you could parse this to get stock OR
        stock = parseInt($option.attr('stock'));  // short-cut: use stock attr

    // only show the first n options:
    var $opts = $("select[name=quantity] option");
    $opts.hide().slice(0, stock).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The second select will show the maximum stock. So what you need to do is store the values in the database, fetch max value and as you are using asp , call the page with ajax which will be shown here as a select option